# How to get specific value from option select - json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to extract data from the option value. For example only ID or UserName. Can you please help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/EBCargoAndCommodityServices/resources/user-form/retrieve", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(dt) {
      $("#customer-list").append('<option value="' + dt.id + dt.contactName + '">' + dt.contactName + '</option>');
    });
    $('#customer-list').change(function() {
      var str = this.value;
      alert(str);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is being alerted in alert(str)?

Comment: It is retrieving id and name,however I will want to take control and extract the id and name seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Let's say for example that dt.id = 1 and dt.contactName is Bartosz.
So you would be alerting 1Bartosz in alert(str)

While building up the options do this,

$("#customer-list").append('<option value="' + `${dt.id}_${dt.contactName}` + '">' + dt.contactName + '</option>'); // Using template literals and concatenating both id and contact name using a delimiter `_`
```

Then, in your change function do this.

```
const info = str.split('_')
/*
info will be an array  with two elements 
info[0] will be id  i.e. 1
info[1] will be contactName i.e. Bartosz
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, the best way would be to store the values you need to use into specific data attributes, then access them using the `.data()` method

```js
    const $ = jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Mocked data for test
        const data = [{"address":"","companyName":"","contactName":"ghkkkkk","email":"","id":22,"surname":"","telephone":0},
        {"address":"","companyName":"","contactName":"asdasd","email":"","id":23,"surname":"","telephone":0}]
        data.forEach(function(dt) {
          $("#customer-list").append('<option data-id="' + dt.id + '" data-name="' + dt.contactName + '" value="' + dt.id + dt.contactName + '">' + dt.contactName + '</option>');
        });
        $('#customer-list').change(function() {
          const selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
          $('#result').text('selected id is: ' + selected.data('id') + ' contact name is : ' + selected.data('name'))
          
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select id="customer-list">
    <option>select an option</option>
  </select>
  <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am getting undefined. My JSON Dummy Array looks as follows:[{"address":"","companyName":"","contactName":"ghkkkkk","email":"","id":22,"surname":"","telephone":0}]. I believe I need to access "nested" object first

Comment: I've changed the snippet to make test runnable :)